# How does Magento URL show product id?

Tags: magento, url, magento2

Magento to always generate product urls in the format:

```
www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/123/s/product-name.html
```

instead of the rewritten:

```
www.example.com/item=123/product-name.html
```

I want easy way edit for new url product view page. (123=product-id)

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal scenario the customer should never see your product-id , the only unique reference available to them should be your SKU so there is no way you can or you should try this. Secondly if you require the product id for development purpose , you can temporarily show it in any form you want :

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); 
$pid = $_product->getId();
```

Be more specific in respect to what you actually want.